# Does Unity3D custom shader work with its GPU skinning automatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gpu, shader, skinning

Hi I'm writing my own shader in mobile, but was wondering if I will break the GPU skinning feature since it's using vertex shader also? My shader is as below:

```
 Shader "Mobile Custom/Specular Map" {
 Properties {
     _ShininessColor("Shininess Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
     _Shininess ("Shininess", Range (0.03, 1)) = 0.078125
     _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
     _SpecMap ("Specular Map", 2D) = "white" {}
 }
 SubShader {
     Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
     LOD 250
     Cull Back

     CGPROGRAM
     #pragma surface surf MobileBlinnPhong exclude_path:prepass nolightmap halfasview interpolateview noshadow nofog nometa nolppv noshadowmask

     inline fixed4 LightingMobileBlinnPhong (SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, fixed3 halfDir, fixed atten) {
         fixed diff = max (0, dot (s.Normal, lightDir));
         fixed nh = max (0, dot (s.Normal, halfDir));
         fixed spec = pow (nh, s.Specular * 128) * s.Gloss;

         fixed4 c;
         c.rgb = (s.Albedo * _LightColor0.rgb * diff + _LightColor0.rgb * spec) * atten;
         UNITY_OPAQUE_ALPHA(c.a);
         return c;
     }

     sampler2D _MainTex;
     sampler2D _SpecMap;
     uniform float4 _ShininessColor;
     half _Shininess;

     struct Input {
         float2 uv_MainTex;
     };

     void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
         fixed4 tex = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
         o.Albedo = tex.rgb;
         o.Gloss = tex2D(_SpecMap, IN.uv_MainTex) * _ShininessColor;
         o.Alpha = tex.a;
         o.Specular = _Shininess;
     }
     ENDCG
 }

 FallBack "Mobile/VertexLit"
 }
```

According to [here](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/04/16/animation-instancing-instancing-for-skinnedmeshrenderer/#crayon-5c36f17cc859a454254557), if using custom shader with instancing, we need to add the instancing shader in our custom shader. Does it apply for GPU skinning too?

Comment: IIRC, skinned meshes are never instanced.  Not sure about the answer to the base question though.

Comment: yup instancing is not related to this question.What I'm trying to point out is that if we use our own custom shader, do we need to import GPU skinning shader to make it work, like the instancing example from the link?

Comment: I mean, I assume you at least need to do the vertex transformation for the bones in the vertex shader... but I'm not sure if you can do that inline, or if you need to import.

Comment: Meaning i have to redo all gpu skinning in my custom vertex shader from scratch, instead of reusing GPU skinning feature in Unity3D?

Comment: Not entirely.  Unity has a lot of built-in transform functions.  There may be one you can just call as a one-liner.  Honestly, though, your best bet, lacking any other options, would be to download the shader sources from the Unity website, find the one you want to expand, and merge your functionality into it.

Comment: So I guess we can conclude custom shader would break existing gpu skinning in unity3d? Yea was looking at those built-in shader. Abit complex, nid some time to study